# Migrating MVC 5 Project to Angular 10

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc

Any suggestion on the approach for migrating .Net MVC 5 project to Angular 10. It's a big project and we cannot just wait for the complete transition. We are kind of looking for a parallel move when we can migrate couple of pages at a time and still keep using the old project.

Comment: It looks like it is necessary to create WEB API as a backend and move Razor pages to Angular as a front end.

Comment: in theorie you just need to switch from view responses to json responses for the actions which you need to switch over, but this depends on what you use to render the pages. if you work with razor pages, which have bindings build in, it might get tricky but if you use razor views i dont see much off a problem with this aproche

Comment: You cannot "migrate" code from one paradigm (and language) to another completely different paradigm and language: you can only do a complete rewrite, which is (frankly) idiotic from a project-management perspective. That said, what makes you think an SPA is the best approach? **What's actually wrong or broken** with your current ASP.NET MVC application? Angular is maintained by Google [and eventually they'll lose interest in it](https://killedbygoogle.com/) just like how [the original AngularJS is now completely dead](https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c)